# How to Edit column Value avoiding Foreign key Error

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, sql-update, foreign-keys

I have a Spring server with use JPA and H2 to store data.

A database table is created using this class:

```
@Entity
public class parametros {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    long idproject;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    List<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public parametros(){
    }
    .../* gets and sets */
}
```

So, JPA and H2 creates automatically a database within a `Table="parametros"` and another `Table="parametros_answers"` like this:

```
Table = "parametros"
ID   |  IDPROJECT   
1    |     3
2    |     6    


Table="parametros_answers"
PARAMETROS_ID   |   ANSWERS
1               |  Masculine
1               |  Female
1               |  Other
2               |  Cocacola
2               |  Pepsi
```

So, the system is creating a foreign key in the `Table = "parametros_answer"` .

Until this point all is OK. The problem comes when I try to EDIT a column value from `Table = "parametros"`. The only way I know to change a column value is using `UPDATE SET` statement. So when I try to do:

`UPDATE PARAMETROS SET IDPROJECT=10 WHERE IDPROJECT=3` this Error Appears:

`Error "DELETE FROM PUBLIC.PARAMETROS WHERE ID=? AND  IDPROJECT=? , cause: "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: ""FK_NFSJ58KBBAYJ84HFJLOCV9JEQ: PUBLIC.PARAMETROS_ANSWERS FOREIGN KEY(PARAMETROS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PARAMETROS(ID) (1)""; SQL statement:
DELETE FROM PUBLIC.PARAMETROS WHERE ID=? AND EXTRA_CONF=? AND IDPROJECT=? AND MULTI_MAXIMUM=? AND MULTI_MINIMUM=? AND NOTE=? AND PERGUNTA=? AND TITLE=? AND TYPE=?  [23503-187]"; SQL statement:`

Comment: Are you sure you're updating? it seems that you were deleting some records

Comment: Yes, it is weird to me too. I just doing `UPDATE PARAMETROS SET IDPROJECT=10 WHERE IDPROJECT=3` in the H2 Console

Comment: What version of h2 are you using?

Comment: My code `session.createSQLQuery("UPDATE PARAMETROS SET IDPROJECT=10 WHERE IDPROJECT=3").executeUpdate();` produces the following `Hibernate: UPDATE PARAMETROS SET IDPROJECT=10 WHERE IDPROJECT=3` and then `System.out.println(rowsUpdated + " rows updated");` prints out `1 rows updated`

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet that produces this problem?

Comment: Why don't you just assign the new value in the Java object? That's what JPA is meant for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I don't know if this solution is the best but is the only one that works for me. Maybe the @highstakes solution will work when the DataBase is empty but in my case is not.
Steps i followed:

1 - Copy the `parametros_answers` table (the one which has the foreig key)  like this:

`CREATE TABLE PARAMETROS_ANSWERS_AUX AS SELECT * FROM PARAMETROS_ANSWERS`

2 - Delete the `parametros_answers` table:

`DROP TABLE PARAMETROS_ANSWER`

2 - After that, I can do the changes I need on `parametros` table:

`UPDATE PARAMETROS SET IDPROJECT=10 WHERE IDPROJECT=3`

3 - I create again the `parametros_answers` by copying that from the `parametros_answers_aux` table:

`CREATE TABLE PARAMETROS_ANSWERS AS SELECT * FROM PARAMETROS_ANSWERS_AUX`

4 - Finally I can delete the auxiliar table `parametros_answers_aux`:

`DROP TABLE PARAMETROS_ANSWERS_AUX`

Answer (score 1):

The exception says what is the problem: you are violating the referential integrity.

- All 'parametros_answers' rows have to point to a 'parametros'. You cannot delete or update 'parametros' without deleting or updating the connections first from 'parametros_answers' in the same transaction.
- Or remove the foreign key constraint.
- Or use entitymanager which automatically deletes/updates these rows if you mark the collection accordingly: @Cascade(value={CascadeType.ALL})

Comment: I want to try your last suggestion, So this `@Cascade(value={CascadeType.ALL})` annotation I have to add above my `List<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();` ?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure this will work for JPQL, I know for delete operations it does not, but it may work for update. You would have to use entitmanager.merge and remove if JPQL does not work.

Comment: One other possibility is relying on the database : use cascade operations on your database schema (if you could change your database schema). The operation is more atomic, faster and safer!